# Why "\t" in c++ have different width?

Tags: c++

This is what I get after I executed the following code:

[image: tab result]

```
cout << "The size of an int is: \t" << sizeof(int) << " bytes.\n";
cout << "The size of an long is: \t" << sizeof(long) << " bytes.\n";
cout << "The size of an double is: \t" << sizeof(double) << " bytes.\n";
```

Why the \t in first row is far shorter than the second or third?

Comment: It's moving to the next tab stop in whatever your console / shell is. The first line is slightly shorter and therefore the tab doesn't move it as far.

Comment: Try some simple experiments. Output one character, followed by `\t`. Output two characters, followed by `\t`. Etc.

Comment: it seems that you are using a 7 spaces tab, tabs (\t) uses a modulus like algorithm to place characters, if you add one extra character to the first line, they will align

Comment: Before asking a question about tab stops, you might try to understand the fundamental reason that they exist...

Comment: this has nothing to do with `C`. You can see this behavior with `echo` or whatever tool to print to console.

Comment: This is why `\t` is not used for formatting. Use spaces.

Comment: In this example it would be extremely easy to align the rightmost `"` of the strings to make them all the same length. Or use the `width` modifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not C++ depending. Tabulation `representation size` depends of the position on the line to the next `Tab stop`

[Tab_key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)

[Tab_stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop)

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia Tab key:

> The tab key Tab ↹ (abbreviation of tabulator key[1] or tabular key[2])
>   on a keyboard is used to advance the cursor **to the next tab stop.**

Wikipedia Tab stop

> A tab stop on a typewriter is a location where the carriage movement
>   is halted by mechanical gears. Tab stops are set manually, and
>   pressing the tab key causes the carriage to go to the next tab stop.
>   In text editors on a computer, the same concept is implemented
>   simplistically with automatic, **fixed tab stops.**

**tldr:** the 'tab' jumps the cursor to the next tabstop, which for example is in a line per 4 characters. So doing a tab at position 3, will jump to 4. tab at position 4 jumps to 8.

Answer (score 4):

Because `\t` aligns to the next tab stop which is 8 characters long in your case. Your first line is 23 characters long, so the next tab stop is at 24 chars. Your second line is 26 characters long, so the next tab stop is at 32 chars.